# SQL - select results from multiple columns WHERE row 1 and row 2 are true

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the birthdate for people from a table where firstname and lastname are in the same row. I'm dealing with 100's of names and I cannot get unique results.

I've tried IN firstname AND lastname, however I am getting matches that are not in the same row.

example: Table "test"

**FirstName**   **LastName**
John              Doe
John              Adams
Jane              Doe
Molly             Jetson
Mary              Wayne

```
SELECT firstname,lastname
FROM test
WHERE lastname IN ( 
'Doe',
'Adams',
'Jetson'
)
AND
firstname IN (
'John',
'John',
'Molly'
);
```

I only want cases where the firstname **matches** the lastname in the **second list**, however I'm getting **ANY** result where the firstname is found OR the lastname is found, so I get both "John Doe" AND "Jane Doe" in the result because the firsname was found AND the lastname was also found.

What I want to return would be:

John Doe
John Adams
Molly Jetson

NOT:
John Doe
Jane Doe
John Adams
Molly Jetson

Answer (score 1):

You can use Table Value Constructor from SQL Server 2008 onwards

```
SELECT t1.FirstName , t1.LastName
FROM Test t1 
JOIN (
    VALUES ('John','Doe'),
           ('John','Adams'),
           ('Molly','Jetson')
)t2(FirstName, LastName)
    ON t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName and t1.LastName = t2.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the logic to use `and` and `or`:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM test
WHERE (lastname = 'Doe' and firstname = 'John') OR
      (lastname = 'Adams' and firstname = 'John') OR
      (lastname = 'Jetson' and firstname = 'Molly')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend concatenating for a tidier where clause:

```
SELECT
firstname,
lastname

FROM
test

WHERE
firstname + ' ' + lastname IN ('John Doe', 'John Adams', 'Molly Jetson')
```